# Using reflection to display data from different custom classes

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection

I want to create a method that displays the information contained in an object, that will work dynamically, with any object.  I'm having trouble handling properties that are other custom classes. In the example below the `Person` has `Phones` and `Occupations` which both are other classes. When the data is displayed, the value on the screen currently is:

```
TestReflection.Person
Name: Mary
Phones: TestReflection.Phones
Occupations: TestReflection.Occupations
```

It just displays the name of class, like `TestReflection.Phones`, rather than the data inside that object.

How can I change this code to show information like this instead?

```
TestReflection.Person
Name: Mary
Phones:
    TestReflection.Phones
    Type: 1
    Number: 555XYZ
Occupations: 
    TestReflection.Occupations
    Type: 5
    Description: Secretary
```

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> listPeson = new List<Person>();
        var person1 = new Person();
        person1.Name = "Mary";
        person1.Phones = new  Phones { new Phone { Type = 1, Number = "555XYZ" } };
        person1.Occupations = new Occupations {new Occupation { Type = 5, Description = "Secretary" }};
        listPeson.Add(person1);
        DynamicExport(listPeson);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DynamicExport<T>(List<T> listReg)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < listReg.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listReg[i].GetType());
            foreach (var item in listReg[i].GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}: {item.GetValue(listReg[i], null)}");
            }
        }
    }
}


class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Phones Phones { get; set; }
    public Occupations Occupations { get; set; }
}

class Phones : List<Phone> { }
class Phone
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

class Occupations : List<Occupation> { }
class Occupation

{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some edits to your question - I hope I understood you correctly.

### If you want to export data

If your question is really about displaying data, then there are better ways to do it than creating your own export method.  The format you are trying to display looks similar to YAML.  There's also JSON and XML.  Using one of these libraries is probably better than writing your own method:

- [YamlDotNet NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YamlDotNet/)
- [Json.NET NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)
- [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer)

### If you want to learn more about reflection

Maybe you're interested in learning more about reflection, and the export is just an example to play around with it.  In that case, let's look at this line:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}: {item.GetValue(listReg[i], null)}");
```

`$"{item.GetValue(listReg[i], null)}"` ends up calling `person1.Phones.ToString()`.  The default behavior of `ToString` just displays the type name.  You could override that behavior, like this:

```
class Phones : List<Phone>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Program.DynamicExportToString(this);

        // ... where DynamicExportToString is a modified version of DynamicExport that
        // builds and returns a string rather than sending it directly to the Console.
    }
}
```

Maybe you want to be able to handle *any* class, even when you cannot override `ToString` in all of the classes you might export.  Then you will need to put some additional logic in the `DynamicExport` method, because...

```
$"{item.Name}: {item.GetValue(listReg[i], null)}"
```

... doesn't work for every situation.  We need to display different things depending on the type of the property.

- Consider how you want to handle null values.  Maybe something like `$"{item.Name}: <null>"`
- Use your existing `$"..."` code if the type is...

  - a [primitive type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive).
  - `DateTime`
  - `String`
  - ... or a `Nullable<>` of one of those types.
- If the type implements `IEnumerable`, loop over the contents of the collection and recursively call your export code for each element.

  - It's important to check for this interface *after* you've checked if the type is a `String`, because `String` implements `IEnumerable`.
- Otherwise, recursively call your export code on this value.

When you call your export code recursively, it would be wise to guard against infinite loops.  If the object you're trying to export contains a circular reference - you could quickly wind up with a [`StackOverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception).  To avoid this, maintain a stack of objects that have already been visited.

I think the above advice is generally applicable whenever you're using reflection to traverse an object graph - whether it's for serialization or any other purpose.
I hope this helps!